# How to return the in Widgets from FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 alreadyJoinedArray = [3KpUkg7flNLHF5RkMoij, 1qFqcGGeSGnoQO2BMrue];
 FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 50,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: SpinKitCircle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(91, 74, 127, 10),
                  size: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      } else {
        alreadyJoinedArray.forEach((gameids) { 
            return RaisedButton(onpressed: () {});
        });

      }
    },
  ),
```

i am getting an error how to solve this problem 
The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState>#2437c):
A build function returned null.

According to my logic it have to return 2 buttons but i am getting the error

Comment: your `} else {` does not return anything - thats why `null` is assumed - `return RaisedButton(onpressed: () {});` is returned from `forEach` callback, not from builder

Comment: same error i am getting i have also tried to return  Container()  after forEach() then i have no error but there is nothing on the screen

Comment: nope i am getting all the documents perfectly

Comment: if you return `Container` only so what do you expect to see? you need some `Column` or `ListView` or something like that

Comment: i want to see the list view of asynchronous data coming from function getData()

Comment: but this array alreadyJoinedArray is the id of some of the documents for that element i want to disable the button not for the rest

Comment: can i post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView.builder rather than that foreach loop. Try like this,

```
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: alreadyJoinedArray.length,
itemBuilder:( context, index){
    return RaisedButton( child: Text("Button $index"), onPressed: (){});
  }
);
```